# Failed to create component ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm using .NET Framework 6.0 and I need to make report, I have installed `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms` but I have yellow mark (warning) next to him, error what I get when I drag report veiwer to win forms is in the picture

[image: Error]

What does cause this problem and how can I fix it?
I watched previous comments about this, but I haven't found anyone who use .NET Framework 6.0 and has this problem.

Comment: For what reason are you using .NET Core rather than .NET Framework?

Comment: Sorry my mistake it's framework

Comment: This normally happens because of a version mismatch, so we need to know the tool you're using to create your form. For some ideas, see [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529104/failed-to-create-component-reportviewer-the-error-message-follows-system-run) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247657/failed-to-create-component-reportviewer-the-error-message-follows).

Comment: Thank you so much, I fixed my problem using these links

Comment: Shall I put up an answer?

Comment: Yes, you can, thank you once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some reasons for the error of
"Failed to create component ‘ReportViewer'" are :

- Mismatch in versions, for example when installing
  microsoft.reporting.winforms when using it from
  Visual Studio. Use a command such as:

  ```
  Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -Version version-number
  ```
- If microsoft.reporting.winforms is not required, remove its reference
  from the project
- A mismatch in versions between the Reporting Services and SQL Server Types packages.

References :

- [failed to create component 'reportviewer'. the error message follows 'system.runtime.interopservices.comexception' vs 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529104/failed-to-create-component-reportviewer-the-error-message-follows-system-run)
- [Failed to create component 'ReportViewer'. The error message follows:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247657/failed-to-create-component-reportviewer-the-error-message-follows)